# time.sleep function returning same time, why?

Tags: python, time

I wrote following code:

```
import time
localtime = time.asctime(time.localtime(time.time()))
for i in range(5):
    print(localtime)
    time.sleep(5)
```

It is returning same time five time with interval of 5 seconds.

However, I understand it should return different time each time after 5 seconds.

Not able to figure out why getting same time 5 times.

Comment: Because you define `localtime` once before the loop, it should be inside the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are only calculating the time once at top of your program, and then printing that value over and over.

One of these might work:

move the caculation into the loop

```
import time

for i in range(5):
    localtime = time.asctime(time.localtime(time.time()))
    print(localtime)
    time.sleep(5)
```

replace the variable which stores the value at the beginning with a function that calculates it

```
import time
def localtime():
    return time.asctime(time.localtime(time.time()))

for i in range(5):
    print(localtime())
    time.sleep(5)
```

---

`localtime = time.asctime(time.localtime(time.time()))` stores the time that you calculate, not the formula for calculating the time.